# angular mat drawer relative button overwritten by drawer content

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat drawer sidenav and content.
In the sidenav i have a button. the button should be above the sidenav and the content and between them.
I am not able to present the button above the two and it gets overwritten by them.[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqpzbj?file=src/app/sidenav-drawer-overview-example.html)

i do prefer not to change the css of the material warpper elements and focus on the button itself if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position: fixed
```

to the button, solved the issue.